# Showing that the Petersen graph does not contain any cycles of length 3 or 4.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that the Petersen graph does not contain any cycles of length $3$ or $4$.

I have been reading about how easy it is proved that the Petersen graph has no cycles of length 3 or 4 but I cannot seem to figure it out.
I can see why it does not have a 3 or 4 cycle from a drawing but I was wondering if there is proof to it.

Comment: Where did you read "about how easy it is" to prove this?  Context is everything.  An author may have created the framework that makes it easy.  By omitting that context, you shift a burden to Readers that might be avoided .  If the problem is of genuine interest to you, you should begin by explaining that interest and the details of your attempt to solve the problem.  Definitions are your friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving this depends on how you define the Petersen graph.

Commonly, the Petersen graph is defined to have the subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ having size 2 as vertices, with two vertices adjacent if the corresponding subsets are distinct.

In this model, a 3-cycle would be three vertices $\{a,b\}$, $\{c,d\}$, $\{e,f\}$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, these three subsets are pairwise disjoint.

You should try to use a similar approach for a 4-cycle: what would it look like in terms of the definition of the vertex set? Can you argue that such a configuration is impossible from the definition of the vertices and their adjacencies?